# RSpec and FactoryGirl explanation for show action

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

Just started learning testing with RSpec and Factory Girl, and came across this test

```
describe "#show" do
        it "render the show template" do
            get :show, id: FactoryGirl.create(:opinion)
            expect(response).to render_template :show
        end
    end
```

To render the show page, I understand that it requires the ID. I just want to understand what this line means `id: FactoryGirl.create(:opinion)`.

Right now I think it means "get the ID of the Opinion object that FactoryGirl is creating", but I want to be certain.

Furthermore, I'm just wondering are there any other ways of writing this same test using another syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get :show, id: FactoryGirl.create(:opinion)
```

Here, you're making a `GET` request and passing the `:id` param along with it to tell it to show the page for that particular `opinion`.

```
id: FactoryGirl.create(:opinion)
```

this is a `param` which is required to make the `/show` request so you're passing it when you make the request. Otherwise the test would fail. Here, you're passing the `opinion` object and Rails will retrieve the `id` for you. Alternatively, you could send the `id` itself instead of the `opinion` object. So, this would work too:

```
get :show, id: FactoryGirl.create(:opinion).id
```

Somewhat, cleaner way of doing it:

You define the `opinion` object first:

```
let(:test_opinion) { FactoryGirl.create(:opinion) }
```

Then, you would use the `test_opinion` object or its `id` later in your tests:

```
describe 'GET #show' do
  context "existing opinion" do
    it 'responds with success' do
      get :show, id: test_opinion.id

      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      expect(response).to render_template :show
    end
  end
end
```

You can also pass more `params` required by your request to render a template properly.

e.g. You could send more comma separated `params` if required:

```
get :show, format: :json, id: FactoryGirl.create(:opinion)
```